# Too many command-line arguments for pg_restore

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to populate a database and am currently inputting:

`pg_restore ${PATHTODATADUMP} -c -v -1 -d ${LOCALDBNAME}`

which results in an error:

`pg_restore: too many command-line arguments (first is "-c")`

How do I get this to work?

Working on Windows btw

Comment: `Usage: pg_restore [OPTION]... [FILE]` So try `pg_restore -c -v -1 -d ${LOCALDBNAME}  ${PATHTODATADUMP}`

Comment: Awesome, that worked, thank you! All I have to do now is to remember my admin password because it's been forever since I've used it :/

Comment: There are a lot of QA about forgotten password ;) Good luck.